# PHP MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are hundreds of questions like this but I can't find a solution , I'm trying to insert an IP address into my table with the following code:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$connect)
  {
   echo 'Failed to connect to database'."</br>";
   die(mysql_error());
  }
 else
  {
    echo 'Connected to database'."</br>";
    mysql_select_db('users', $connect);
    if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_info (IP) VALUES (`127.0.0.1`)",$connect))
     {
      echo 'query success';
     }
    else
    {
     echo 'query failed'."</br>".mysql_error();
    }


    mysql_close($connect);
  }
?>
```

But it keeps returning the following error:

> Unknown column '127.0.0.1' in 'field list'

What's wrong with my query? The type is set to Varchar(15) and yes i know i'm vulnerable to SQL injections right now.

Nubcake

Comment: Use proper quotes for your value: `'` not backticks

Comment: Do you know that `\`` is used to quote field names/table names?

Comment: "..and yes I know I'm vulnerable to SQL injections right now", actually in this example you're not vulnerable to anything

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4):

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_info (IP) VALUES (`127.0.0.1`)",$connect))
```

should be

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_info (IP) VALUES ('127.0.0.1')",$connect))
```

Notice the single `'` quotes, backtricks `` ` `` are used for columns and table names.